# To establish the truth of a logical predicate expression by the specification of variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Please, help me to establish the truth of a logical expression by specifying method.

> ∀x A(x) ∨ ∀x B(x) = ∀x∀y(A(x) ∨ B(y)))

As i know, i should get equal expressians on both sides of "=". So, i used some logical rules to solve it, but i can not get it equal. 
Specifying:

x={a,b}

y={c,d}

**∀x A(x) = A(a) ∧ A(b)**

**∀x B(x) = B(a) ∧ B(b)**

**Left side:**
 A(a) ∧ A(b) ∨ B(a) ∧ B(b)

**Right side:** ∀x[∀y(A(x) ∨ B(y))]= ∀x [(A(x) ∨ B(c)) ∧ (A(x) ∨ B(d))] = ...  = A(a) ∨ B(d), B(d) ∨ B(c) ∨ A(d), A(b) ∨ B(d), A(a) ∨ B(d) ∨ B(c)

As you can see, this two parts are not equal to each other. What is more, there are some **"extra"** variables: ***B(d)*** and ***B(c)***.  They do not even exist on the left side..

Probably i miss some key points. I asked my teacher about it, but i did not get appropriate answer.

So, why it happens and how to prove it?

**Please help me. Your help will be greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have multiple quantifiers in the same statement, the quantifiers have to range over the exact same domain. So, you can't do what you did, and say that $x$ ranges over the objects $a$ and $b$, but that $y$ ranges over the objects $c$ and $d$.

Here is how you *can* make sense of the equivalence. In general, we could say that we have objects $a,b,c,...$ in our domain. So:

$$\forall x A(x) \lor \forall x B(x) =$$

$$(A(a) \land A(b) \land ...) \lor (B(a) \land B(b) \land ...)=$$

$$(A(a) \lor B(a)) \land (A(a) \lor B(b)) \land ... \land (A(b) \lor B(a)) \land (A(b) \lor B(b)) \land ... =$$

$$\forall y (A(a) \lor B(y)) \land \forall y (A(b) \lor B(y)) \land ... =$$

$$\forall x \forall y (A(x) \lor B(y))$$

Comment: You give answers like this often, but I think it would be beneficial to make it clear that this is an intuition only and that this would not be considered a valid proof of the statement. (Personally, I wouldn't even use this as an intuition because it doesn't generalize to non-classical logics, but I understand that most people/students will never work with a non-classical logic.)

Comment: @DerekElkins Yes, I got sloppy ... :( Typically I do add a statement to this effect, but in this situation I figured the OP would see the crucial difference with their own solution and get the point.

Comment: @Bram28 can you make a more detailed solution? My teacher is not satisfied with that answer, thank you.

Comment: @Nikitonix good for your teacher! As an answer, it is indeed too sloppy, and certainly does not constitute a proof...I was mainly pointing out that within a single statement, all quantifiers quantify over the same set of objects ... the domain of discourse.  Now, to actually prove the equivalence there are several methods .... do you have an idea what method your teacher is looking for?

Comment: @Bram28 He said that i should use specification method. At the link below, in first 5 paragraphs you can see an example of it. But still, the quantifiers are not ranging over the exact same domain... In this book it is written as x=a, b and y=c,d ...
https://translate.google.ru/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&u=http://sceptic-ratio.narod.ru/ma/dm1-5d.htm&prev=search

Comment: @Nikitonix Hmm, that specification method is a bit sloppy as well, but fine. Now, looking at example 1, I see that you are allowed to replace variables with other variables. So,for your problem, I would first replace $\forall x\ B(x)$ with $\forall y \ B(y)$, and then use that specification method.

Comment: @Bram28 I think It seems to be a bit strange too. Please, can you solve it? Because during the time i was solving it again i had some troubles and inaccuracies and spent so much time, so i don't even know how to end it with succes. Some troubles still exist.